# get end values from lambda expressions method parameters

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

basically I want to get the values of the parameters of a called method like this:

```
var x = 1;
var a = 2;
var b = 3;
Do<HomeController>(o => o.Save(x, "Jimmy", a+b+5, Math.Sqrt(81)));

public static void Do<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expression) where T : Controller
{
  // get the values 1,Jimmy,10,9 here
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, you'd need to drill into the expression, find the `MethodCallExpression`, and then look at the arguments to it. Note that we don't have the value of `o`, so we've got to assume that the arguments to the method don't rely on that. Also we're still assuming that the lambda expression just relies on it being a `MethodCallExpression`?

EDIT: Okay, here's an edited version which evaluates the arguments. However, it assumes you're *not* really using the lambda expression parameter within the arguments (which is what the `new object[1]` is about - it's providing a null parameter, effectively).

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Foo
{
    public void Save(int x, string y, int z, double d)
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = 1;
        var a = 2;
        var b = 3;
        ShowValues<Foo>(o => o.Save(x, "Jimmy", a + b + 5, Math.Sqrt(81)));
    }

    static void ShowValues<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expression)
    {
        var call = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (call == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a method call");
        }
        foreach (Expression argument in call.Arguments)
        {
            LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(argument, 
                                                        expression.Parameters);
            Delegate d = lambda.Compile();
            object value = d.DynamicInvoke(new object[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("Got value: {0}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Omu: But do you really want code which would break - at execution time only - if you used *any* other form of lambda expression? If you're *always* going to be calling Save, why not just pass the parameters in directly?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I'm going to be calling lots of other methods with different parameters, I didn't knew that I can call only with constant values, I guess I'm going to have to investigate this further

Comment: @Omu: This is the problem with just dumping code into a question with no explanation. I did *say* it was brittle, and would fail as soon as you started using any other pattern...

Comment: @Jon Skeet I just try to make the questions as simple as possible

Comment: @Omu: I've edited my answer to match the question. I think it does what you want, although I'd still say it's pretty brittle.

Comment: The fact that I am allowed to do this sort of stuff scares me a little. We have just used this for a transparent way to generate memoiser keys.

Answer (score 4):

As Jon said you can check to see if the expression is a MethodCallExpression

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program.Do<Controller>(c => c.Save(1, "Jimmy"));
    }

    public static void Do<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expression) where T : Controller
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (body != null)
        {
            foreach (var argument in body.Arguments)
            {
                var constant = argument as ConstantExpression;
                if (constant != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(constant.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Controller
{
    public void Save(int id, string name)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty brittle either way. I doubt it's the best approach, but we don't have much context.

Answer (score 3):

My universal answer is below. I hope it will help you and somebody else.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var parameterExpressions = methodCallExpr.Arguments;
foreach (var param in method.GetParameters())
{
    var parameterExpression = parameterExpressions[counter];
    var paramValueAccessor = Expression.Lambda(parameterExpression);
    var paramValue = paramValueAccessor.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
    dict[param.Name] = paramValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that is designed to work with any expression — in the sense that it doesn’t fundamentally assume that you are passing in a method-call expression. However, it is not complete. You will have to fill in the rest.

```
public static IEnumerable<object> ExtractConstants<T>(
        Expression<Action<T>> expression)
{
    return extractConstants(expression);
}
private static IEnumerable<object> extractConstants(Expression expression)
{
    if (expression == null)
        yield break;

    if (expression is ConstantExpression)
        yield return ((ConstantExpression) expression).Value;

    else if (expression is LambdaExpression)
        foreach (var constant in extractConstants(
                ((LambdaExpression) expression).Body))
            yield return constant;

    else if (expression is UnaryExpression)
        foreach (var constant in extractConstants(
                ((UnaryExpression) expression).Operand))
            yield return constant;

    else if (expression is MethodCallExpression)
    {
        foreach (var arg in ((MethodCallExpression) expression).Arguments)
            foreach (var constant in extractConstants(arg))
                yield return constant;
        foreach (var constant in extractConstants(
                ((MethodCallExpression) expression).Object))
            yield return constant;
    }

    else
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

For the case that you have mentioned, this already works:

```
// Prints:
// Jimmy (System.String)
// 1 (System.Int32)
foreach (var constant in Ext.ExtractConstants<string>(
        str => Console.WriteLine("Jimmy", 1)))
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", constant.ToString(),
                                   constant.GetType().FullName);
```

For more complex lambda expressions that employ other types of expression nodes, you will have to incrementally extend the above code. Every time you use it and it throws a `NotImplementedException`, here is what I do:

- Open the Watch window in the debugger
- Look at the `expression` variable and its type
- Add the necessary code to handle that expression type

Over time the method will become more and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public override IQueryable<Image> FindAll(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Image, dynamic>> Id)
        {
            dynamic currentType = Id.Parameters[0];
            var id = currentType.Type.GUID;
            var result = (_uniwOfWork as UnitOfWork).uspGetImages(id.ToString());
            return FindAll();
        }
```

use keyword dynamic.