# How to get the referred string of an Action<string> delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I have a method that expects an `Action<string>`

I call the method as follows:

```
commandProcessor.ProcessCommand(s=> ShowReceipt("MyStringValue"))


ProccessCommand(Action<string> action)
{
  action.Invoke(...); // How do I get the reffered string?
}
```

Do I have to use `Expression<Action<string>>` ? If so, how do I get the parameter values?

Comment: What reffered string? You're code expects _you_ to pass a string to the invoke method (which btw is redudant you do action(...) ). There's no string bound to the action<string> argument.

Comment: Is action.Invoke(...) not the same as action(...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would indeed have to use `Expression<Action<string>>`... and even then you'd have to make some assumptions or write quite a lot of code to make it very robust.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766698/get-values-from-lambda-expressions-parameter) may help you - it's pretty similar - but I would try to think of an alternative design if possible. Expression trees *are* great, and very interesting... but I typically think of them as a bit of a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would call it like this:

```
 commandProcessor.ProcessCommand(s=> ShowReceipt(s))
```

or simply

```
 commandProcessor.ProcessCommand(ShowReceipt)
```

and supply the string to the action in the called method:

```
 ProcessCommand(Action<string> action) 
 { 
  action("MyStringValue"); 
 }
```

Comment: my string value is different. What I now do is to have an extra parameter string.  ProcessCommand(Action<string> action, string str)