# Extracting input arguments from Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have method that accepts LambdaExpression as a parametar

```
    public void SomeMethod(Expression<Func<SomeObject, bool>> predicate)
    { }
```

inside this method I would like to extract the members and the arguments values from the expression Body. Is this possible and how can be achieved?

Method can be invoked like this:

```
    SomeMethod(t=> t.Id == 3 && t.Name=="Name");
```

or

```
    SomeMethod(t=> t.Id.Equals(3));
```

or

```
    SomeMethod(t=> t.Id > 3 || t.Id = 1);
```

etc. You get the point.

Comment: [Get end values from lambda expressions method parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766698/get-end-values-from-lambda-expressions-method-parameters)

Comment: Check this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The solution you are looking for is called [Expression Tree Visitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521.aspx).
By using it you can go though lambda expression members and arguments.

Also this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx) may be useful, it contains code for lambda expression partial evaluator in case arguments in lambda expression is not a constants