# How to get arguments from an Expression where TDelegate is a callback

Tags: c#, linq, caching, lambda

I'm attempting to write a simple generic cache but running into problems with generating unique enough keys with using `System.Func` as a callback.

What I ideally want is to be able to pass in an invocable delegate of some description so that the cache itself can get the value, and determine a key all from the same expression.  Right now I'm getting exceptions because I'm not passing in an argument that implements or inherits from MethodCallExpression. What should I be using instead of a `System.Func` for this intended behaviour?

```
public class SimpleCacheKeyGenerator : ICacheKey
{
    public string GetCacheKey<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
    {
        var body = (MethodCallExpression) action.Body; //!!! Exception Raised - action.Body is FieldExpression

        ICollection<object> parameters = (from MemberExpression expression in body.Arguments
                                          select
                                              ((FieldInfo) expression.Member).GetValue(
                                                  ((ConstantExpression) expression.Expression).Value)).ToList();

        var sb = new StringBuilder(100);
        sb.Append(body.Type.Namespace);
        sb.Append("-");
        sb.Append(body.Method.Name);

        parameters.ToList().ForEach(x =>
                                        {
                                            sb.Append("-");
                                            sb.Append(x);
                                        });

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class InMemoryCache : ICacheService
{
    private readonly ICachePolicy _cachePolicy;
    private readonly ICacheKey _cacheKey;

    public InMemoryCache(ICachePolicy cachePolicy, ICacheKey cacheKey)
    {
        _cachePolicy = cachePolicy;
        _cacheKey = cacheKey;
    }

    public T Get<T>(Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
    {
        var cacheID = _cacheKey.GetCacheKey(() => getItemCallback);
        var item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheID) as T;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = getItemCallback();

            if (_cachePolicy.RenewLeaseOnAccess)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheID, getItemCallback, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, _cachePolicy.ExpiresAfter);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheID, getItemCallback, null, DateTime.UtcNow + _cachePolicy.ExpiresAfter, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: the type of expression<func... is lambdaexpression not MethodCallExpression

Comment: Do you have multiple underlying methods that are wrapped by a Func<T> for the same type T return value? If not you could either get the hashcode of the Func<T> (same signature will generally result in same hashcode) or use the type of T as your key. Otherwise, in what context is it determined which  method to pass in as a Func<T>? Could something in that context provide a key?

Comment: Is this a response to that quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766698/get-end-values-from-lambda-expressions-method-parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you can't easily use both the Expression> and Func representing the same thing without duplicating the code.

You could possibly convert Expression> to a Func with LambdaExpression>.Compile() method, but that could create a performance problem, since Compile actually uses assembly emit, which is quite expensive.

Here is how i would implement the same thing without using Expressions and compilation.
You can find the same pattern everywhere in the standard Linq extensions.

Pass your argument as a separate object.
The type you use as an argument will be used for type inference for the delegate, and the argument itself will provide the arguments for the delegate at the same type.

Note that the cache in this implementation works because of the default ToString implementation of the anonimous objects used as arguments.

```
void Main()
{
    var computeCount = 0;
    var item1 = GetCached(new{x = 1, y = 2}, (arg)=>{computeCount++; return arg.x + arg.y;});
    Console.WriteLine(item1);
    var item2 = GetCached(new{x = 1, y = 2}, (arg)=>{computeCount++; return arg.x + arg.y;});
    Console.WriteLine(item2);
    var item3 = GetCached(new{x = 1, y = 3}, (arg)=>{computeCount++; return arg.x + arg.y;});
    Console.WriteLine(item3);
    Console.WriteLine("Compute count:");
    Console.WriteLine(computeCount);
}
Dictionary<string, object> _cache = new Dictionary<string, object>();
E GetCached<T, E>(T arg, Func<T,E> getter)
{
    // Creating the cache key.
    // Assuming T implements ToString correctly for cache to work.
    var cacheKey = arg.ToString();

    object result;

    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out result))
    {
        var newItem = getter(arg);
        _cache.Add(cacheKey, newItem);
        return newItem;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cache hit: {0}", cacheKey);
    }

    return (E)result;
}
```

Console output:

```
3
Cache hit: { x = 1, y = 2 }
3
4
Compute count:
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this exception because `(() => getItemCallback)` means `(() => { return getItemCallback; })`

That's why `action.Body` is not a method call, it is the return statement. If you change your code to `(() => getItemCallback())` you should not have the error. But you won't have any arguments.

To obtain arguments of the base call, you will have to change your code to accept an Expression and Compile your lambda.

```
public T Get<T>(Expression<Func<T>> getItemCallbackExpression) where T : class
{
    var cacheID = _cacheKey.GetCacheKey(getItemCallbackExpression);
    var item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheID) as T;
    if (item == null)
    {
        item = getItemCallback.Compile()();

        if (_cachePolicy.RenewLeaseOnAccess)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheID, getItemCallback, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, _cachePolicy.ExpiresAfter);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheID, getItemCallback, null, DateTime.UtcNow + _cachePolicy.ExpiresAfter, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
    }

    return item;
}
```

I won't recommend this approach because compiling an expression takes time.

It may be easier and more performant to manually generate cache keys. If you really want to automatically manage cache keys. You may have a look to Aspect Oriented Programmation using castle.Core or PostSharp. Theses tools will allow you to automatically add code to some of your methods and automatically add cache logic.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code as below, I got the expected result this way, so you can try this, I hope this would be helpful.

```
 public class SimpleCacheKeyGenerator
{
    public string GetCacheKey<T, TObject>(Expression<Func<T, TObject>> action)
    {
        var body = (MethodCallExpression) action.Body;
        ICollection<object> parameters = body.Arguments.Select(x => ((ConstantExpression) x).Value).ToList();

        var sb = new StringBuilder(100);
        sb.Append(body.Type.Namespace);
        sb.Append("-");
        sb.Append(body.Method.Name);

        parameters.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            sb.Append("-");
            sb.Append(x);
        });

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class InMemoryCache
{
    public void Get<T, TObject>(Expression<Func<T, TObject>> getItemCallback)
    {
        var generator = new SimpleCacheKeyGenerator();
        Console.WriteLine(generator.GetCacheKey(getItemCallback));
    }
}
```

main:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cache = new InMemoryCache();

        var tt = new SomeContextImpl();
        cache.Get<SomeContextImpl, string>(x => x.Any("hello", "hi"));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

somcontextimpl:

```
 public class SomeContextImpl
{
    public string Any(string parameter1, string parameter2) { return ""; }
}
```