# Function for automated testing of multi-parameter methods; using delegates and generics

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, delegates, automated-tests

I've recently started learning about C# generics and delegates. After having learned some, I created this function as a means of automatically testing the output of any single parameter method: Using generics and delegates, it accepts a function with supplied types,a testing value and expected value.

```
public static class Testing
{
    public static void FunctionTest<FunctionArgType, FunctionReturnType>(Func<FunctionArgType, FunctionReturnType> functionName, FunctionArgType testValue, FunctionReturnType expectedValue)
    {
        string passFail;
        var returnedValue = functionName(testValue);            
        if (returnedValue.Equals(expectedValue))
        {
            passFail = "Pass";
        }
        else
        {
            passFail = "Fail";
        }
        ConsoleLogger(functionName.Method.ToString(), passFail, testValue, expectedValue, returnedValue);

    }
}
```

Here are two very simple methods to test:

```
public static double SimpleSquare(double num)
{
    return num * num;
}
public static char FirstLetter(string value)
{
    return value[0];
}
```

Here is the implementation of my testing function:

```
Testing.FunctionTest<double, double>(SimpleSquare, 5, 25);
Testing.FunctionTest<double, double>(SimpleSquare, 4, 20);

Testing.FunctionTest<string, char>(FirstLetter, "Ryan", 'R');
Testing.FunctionTest<string, char>(FirstLetter, "Brian", 'n');
```

And console output:

```
Double SimpleSquare(Double) Pass
Input: 5; Expected: 25; Returned: 25
-------------------------------------------------
Double SimpleSquare(Double) Fail
Input: 4; Expected: 20; Returned: 16
-------------------------------------------------
Char FirstLetter(System.String) Pass
Input: Ryan; Expected: R; Returned: R
-------------------------------------------------
Char FirstLetter(System.String) Fail
Input: Brian; Expected: n; Returned: B
-------------------------------------------------
```

**My question**: Can my testing function be extended to include testing methods with multiple parameters? Such as:

```
public static double SimpleSum(double num1, double num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

Also, being new to this side of C#, and automated testing in general, is this a decent approach and am I headed in a good direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many overloads of `Func<>` having up to 16 parameters. However, you will have to write yourself different overloads of your testing method in order to use them.

---

But there is another solution: Pass a lambda expression to your testing method having only a return value (`Func<TReturn>`) and only pass and log the expected result.

```
public static void FunctionTest<TReturn>(
    Func<TReturn> functionName, 
    TReturn expectedValue)
{
    string passFail;
    var returnedValue = functionName();
    if (returnedValue.Equals(expectedValue)) {
        passFail = "Pass";
    } else {
        passFail = "Fail";
    }
    ConsoleLogger(functionName.Method.ToString(), passFail, expectedValue, returnedValue);
}
```

Using this additional function:

```
public static double Mult(double a, double b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

Test like this:

```
Testing.FunctionTest<double>(() => SimpleSquare(5), 25);
Testing.FunctionTest<double>(() => Mult(3, 4), 12);
```

C# can infer the function type. Therfore you can also drop the generic parameter when calling:

```
Testing.FunctionTest(() => SimpleSquare(5), 25);
Testing.FunctionTest(() => Mult(3, 4), 12);
```

---

If you still want to log the input values, you can do it in 2 ways:

1. Use A `params` argument. It lets you pass an arbitrary number of parameters to the function:

   ```
   public static void FunctionTest<TReturn>(
       Func<TReturn> functionName,
       TReturn expectedValue,
       params object[] args)
   { .. }
   ```
2. Use reflection in order to analyze the lambda expression and directly extract the parameters from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3766713/880990.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite it in the following manner:

```
public static void FunctionTest<FunctionReturnType>(Func<FunctionReturnType> function, FunctionReturnType expectedValue)        string passFail;
            var returnedValue = function();
            if (returnedValue.Equals(expectedValue))
            {
                passFail = "Pass";
            }
            else
            {
                passFail = "Fail";
            }
            ConsoleLogger(function.Method.ToString(), passFail, expectedValue, returnedValue);

        }

Testing.FunctionTest(() => SimpleSum(5,5), 10);
```